# How to toggle between views in Access 2010

Tags: microsoft-access-2010

I have a form which displays count sheets. One view is with the pre-count qty and the other is without the pre-count qty. This was originally developed in Access 2003. I can not toggle between the two views in Access 2010>

Comment: You should change the title to reflect correct version of Access

Answer (score 0):

From File menu you can choose between **Form View** and **Layout View**

[image]